# Using MinMaxScaler on Training Set... Do I need to scale the input for a prediction as well?

Tags: classification, scikit-learn, feature-scaling

I know this is a rookie question, but I'm having trouble with getting predictions out of a model. I use a MinMaxScaler() function on the training set as seen below...

```
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
X_train = scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = scaler.transform(X_test)
```

Now that I have trained and saved the model, I'm trying to run the model using this code...

```
filename='cb1.sav'
loaded_model = pickle.load(open(filename, 'rb'))
predicted_y = loaded_model.predict_proba(sys.argv[1:])

print(predicted_y)
```

I pass all the values for the prediction in as arguments like...

```
#python3 ./test.py 43 28 0.2348 0.00002934 8
```

Resulting in an array in sys.argv where sys.argv[1:] represents all the X values in correct order and skipping the first since the first is the name of the file (test.py)

**Question:**
Do I need to perform any scaling or transformation on the sys.argv[1:0] values?

Comment: Can you please post the actual code for the model. Is pre-processing included there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.  Any preprocessing that you did manually before the model object was trained needs to be applied to prediction data; the model is expecting the inputs in the same format as when you trained it.

The easiest way to do that, if you used sklearn preprocessors, is to also save all the preprocessing steps and load those in your prediction script.  This is made even easier by putting them together with your model into a `Pipeline` and just fitting and saving the entire pipeline as a single object.

Comment: I know how to do none of those things :-)

Time to go learn! This stuff is fun!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the scaling has to be performed at inference time as well.

Ben Reiniger has an excellent suggestion in terms of using a Pipeline to host the scaler and the model as a convenient single artifact for deployment.

An alternate can also be to use the [BatchNormalization](https://keras.io/api/layers/normalization_layers/batch_normalization/) layer as one of your model's layers, and that will also ensure that you end up with a single artifact to be deployed.

Additional example [here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-accelerate-learning-of-deep-neural-networks-with-batch-normalization/).